# How to show a dynamic list in the email body using mailjet

Tags: reactjs, jsx, mailjet

I'm using mailjet to send emails in my website. The emails sent include variables e.g name, email address, phone no...etc. I'm using template literals to include the variables and it is working fine when it is just one variable, but when I want to map over an array it shows [object Object] for every element instead of showing the actual variable.
How do I achieve iterating an array?
I was using the normal jsx syntax.
Here is part of the code:

```
const request = await mailjet
    .post('send', {
        version: 'v3.1'
    })
    .request({
        Messages: [{
            From: {
                Email: "email@gmail.com",
                Name: "Pilot"
            },
            To: [{
                Email: "anotheremail@gmail.com",
                Name: "Brian"
            }],
            Subject: "My first email!",
            TextPart: "This is the text part",
            HTMLPart: `<h3>Order from website</h3>
                                                <p>Hi, I would like to order the following: </p>
                                                <ul>
                                                    ${cartItems.map(cartItem => (
                                                        <li key={cartItem._id}>{cartItem.name} {cartItem.quantity}kgs</li>
                                                    ))}
                                                </ul> 
                                                <p>Here are my contact details:</p> 
                                                <p>Name: ${firstName} ${lastName}</p>
                                                <p>Email: ${email}</p>
                                                <p>Mobile: ${mobile}</p>`,
            TemplateLanguage: true
        }]
    });
```

This is how the cartItems look like:

```
[{ id: 1, name: 'Orange', quantity: 2 },{ id: 2, name: 'Pineapple', quantity: 9 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop in your template email like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for fruit in var:fruits %}
    <li>{{fruit.name}} {{fruit.quantity}}</li>      
      {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and send the array in the variables